# Example where finite expectation does not imply random variable is finite

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For weak law and strong law of large numbers, we have the assumption: $E[|X_1|] <\infty$.

What's an example of a random variable where this is a weaker requirement than $|X_1| < \infty$?

Put another way, why doesn't the weak and strong law just have the precondition that $|X_1| < \infty$?

Comment: If a rv is integrable (i.e. $E|X|<\infty $) then it is finite a.a. - if a rv is finite a.a., it does not mean it is integrable. Integrability is a stronger condition than a.a. finiteness

Comment: Yes you're right. I realized after I posted that it is a stronger condition.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one; $\mathbb{E}(|X|) < \infty \implies |X|< \infty$ almost surely.

Comment: If $|X| = \infty$ on a set of measure 0, then $E[|X|] < \infty$ right? This can be seen from law of total expectation, where $E[|X| | |X| <\infty] P( |X| = \infty)  = \infty * 0 = 0$ (by convention, we define $ 0 * \infty = 0$ for abstract integrals / expectations)

Comment: @user3180 no. Example: $X(\omega)=1/\omega, \omega \in (0,1],X(0)=\infty,dP=d\omega$ on $[0,1]$.